# A linear programming to obtain "canonical basis of convex cone"

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

In my research a I need to solve the linear equation (getting its null space) under some constraints.

The matrix is given below:

[image]

The constraints shall be (x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdc2.png)...x[16]>0, x[17]...x[20] arbitary...)

The solutions shall actually be a canonical combination of a lot of vectors, (canonical combination means possitive sums of vectors). And I wish to get those vectors. Is there any software package that could do this?

IS there a name for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check [CellNetAnalyzer](http://www2.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/projects/cna/cna.html) toolbox. It has a functionality to compute the basis vector for the (convex) cone formed by the intersection of a matrix kernel and the positive orthant. This basis is called extreme generator/current in the toolbox (see the manual). The toolbox was intended for stoichiometric network analysis, but you can easily search for the function that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have some $r \times c$ matrix $A$ with $c\geq r$. Apply complete Gauss-Jordan Elimination (both phases) to get this into reduced row-echelon form, i.e. looking like $[I_r|M]$ where $I_r$ is the $r \times r$ identity and $M$ is what remains.

Now take the matrix $[-M|I_{c-r}]^T$ will have the columns which will characterize the null space of $A$ for you. Not sure if they will possibly be linearly dependent or not, but run Gram-Schmidt (QR factorization) to find out for sure.

(Notice the correctness by construction: $[I_r|M] \times [-M|I_{c-r}]^T = I$.)

Comment: The null space basis vector can be computed, but I want to intersect this null space with the first quadrant. The result should be able to be represented by a set of vectors, say v[1]~v[100], and the final solution should be sum(i=1..100,a[i]v[i],a[i]>0).... Is there a way to do it?